# Firebase database rules: cant read an another collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

can you help me please?

I have these rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /locations/{document=**} {
        allow read, write;
      }
      match /Users/{userId} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
  }
}
```

So when I am trying to access the 'locations' collection via Firebase Simulator I get an error:

> Simulated data access denied

Here is a 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAOnR.png)

The path in the Location field of the Simulator is

```
/databases/(default)/documents/locations
```

I CAN access and write a data to the Users collection from my app (when authorized of course) but the problem is that I need to allow the access to the Locations collection without any permissions. I can't read a 'locations' collection

Any advice highly welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you are specifying is incorrect.
It should be **only `locations/documentID`** instead of *`databases/(default)/documents/locations/documentID`*.

`/databases/(default)/documents` is basically a tooltip of where you are.